# Configure Application Restrictions for Javascript Maps API key used in Android/iOS Webview application

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a cordova application using the Google javascript Maps API to load maps in Webview. The API is configured to use a key and loads correctly when no referrer application restrictions are applied to the key.

My question is how should I configure application restriction referrers for the API key. In Android this is fairly simple - I just have to add the referrers that appear in the console warning when trying to load the API with restrictions enabled. In iOS however the referrer URLS appear to depend on the development environment, so aren't suitable for configuring as referrers.

Is it possible to reliably configure referrer restrictions for webview applications in general, and for iOS in particular?

Comment: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @wf9a5m75, but as I have an existing application using the Javascript API my first choice is to configure my API keys to continue using that API. If it turns out Google doesn't want to support using the Javascript API in webview I'll look into using the Google platform APIs.